Arrow function this scope is undefined even when using .call or .apply
var obj = {
    method : () =>{
        console.log(this)
    }
}
obj.method.apply(obj)

I'm trying to use .call or .apply to set the this context for an arrow function, but this remains undefined. I understand that arrow functions have a lexical this binding, but I was hoping .call or .apply would still allow me to change the context. Can someone explain why this is happening or suggest an alternative approach?

Arrow functions don't allow changing the context. Use common functions.

"Arrow functions don't have their own bindings to this, arguments, or super, and should not be used as methods." Arrow function expressions.

"For similar reasons, the call(), apply(), and bind() methods are not useful when called on arrow functions, because arrow functions establish this based on the scope the arrow function is defined within, and the this value does not change based on how the function is invoked." Cannot be used as methods

"Can someone explain why this is happening" because that's what's supposed to be happening by spec. The alternative approach would be to not use arrow functions. It's exceptionally unclear why you want to use them here anyway: no arrow function is literally shorter and works like you want it. Why do you believe you shouldn't be using that or why do you think an arrow function is called for?


I understand that arrow functions have a lexical this binding

Yes.

but I was hoping .call or .apply would still allow me to change the context.

No. It's purely lexical.

Can someone explain why this is happening

That is how arrow functions are designed

or suggest an alternative approach?

Don't use an arrow function if you don't want lexical binding. Lexical binding is the point of arrow functions.


var obj = {
  method() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}

obj.method();



